# Python + RaspberryPI can't import GPIO after installing: ImportError: No module named _GPIO

Tags: python, import, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have a RPi 2 (running raspbian jessie with pixel) and just tried to install the GPIO module:

I have downloaded and installed from source. Then I issue commands:

```
pi@raspberry:python
>>> import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "RPi/GPIO/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from RPi._GPIO import *
ImportError: No module named _GPIO
```

so then I tried using sudo:

```
pi@raspberry:sudo python
>>> import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "RPi/GPIO/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from RPi._GPIO import *
ImportError: No module named _GPIO
```

Then I removed the module from python, and installed it again using pip:

```
pi@raspberry:sudo pip install RPi.GPIO
pi@raspberry:sudo python
>>> import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "RPi/GPIO/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from RPi._GPIO import *
ImportError: No module named _GPIO
```

Then I removed the module from python, and installed it again using apt-get:

```
pi@raspberry:sudo apt-get update
pi@raspberry:sudo apt-get -y install python-rpi.gpio
pi@raspberry:sudo python
>>> import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "RPi/GPIO/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from RPi._GPIO import *
ImportError: No module named _GPIO
```

It seems it has nothing to do with the install method, so I'm assuming it's something to do with either Raspbian Jessie + pixel or the current version of python-gpio is broken/incompatible.

Its strange because I am not importing "_GPIO", I am importing "GPIO", which indicates to me that my python syntax is not the culprit.

Could somebody please recommend what I should try next?

Also I searched [this exact error](https://www.google.com/#q=%22ImportError:+No+module+named+_GPIO%22) on Google and got 1 result which was not helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you have a dir called RPi in your current dir,so change your python file to another dir which doesn't have ,it works for me...hope it's helpful :)

Comment: You were absolutely correct! It turns out that after I downloaded the source files and navigated to the directory where setup.py was located, I never actually left that directory when I started python and as you mention it did contain conflicting files. Once I ran python from another shell in another directory the module imported just fine. Thanks!